Change n install location
I've got a macbook pro and I'm trying to setup my local environment. Because I develop websites that sometimes need different node version, I want to use "n" as node version management.
I'm using brew.
I've downloaded "n" with brew, but this is creating a problem. "n" will install his node version in /usr/local/bin/node, but "n" uses /opt/homebrew/bin/node for his active node version:

How do I get "n" to install his node version in uses /opt/homebrew/bin/node so I can use those versions.

If n is not finding the correct binary, you can set the N_PREFIX environment variable to tell n where to look for Node.js binaries. Add the following to your shell configuration file (.bashrc, .zshrc, etc.) to set the N_PREFIX:
export N_PREFIX="/usr/local"

After adding this line, restart your terminal or run source ~/.bashrc (or the appropriate configuration file for your shell) to apply the changes.
Now, when you install a new version of Node.js with n, it should be installed to the correct location, and n should be able to use it properly.

Three approaches, pick any one:

set N_PREFIX to /opt/homebrew to have n use the homebrew home location and n will overwrite the homebrew managed version of node (may fight)
change PATH to have /usr/local/bin before /opt/homebrew/bin to have the node installed by n found before the homebrew version
uninstall the homebrew managed version of node (if you take this approach, npm uninstall -g npm before removing node)

(You can combine option 1 and 3.)

I added a detailed walk-through of option 3 to n documentation: https://github.com/tj/n/blob/master/docs/changing-node-location.md
